# GDB: skip through loop iterations

Tags: debugging, gdb, visual-studio-debugging

How can i skip over n iterations using GDB? I'm trying to debug a for loop and i want to get to iteration 703, without typing next 703 times.

Attention: I want to remain in the loop, only to skip n iterations.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

Considering this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    printf("%d\n",i);
}
```

In GDB you have to type: **'break n'** ( where n is the line number for the 'for' loop) and then **'c x'** - where x is the number of times you want to skip the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try a breakpoint count: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Conditions.html

`(gdb) ignore bnum count`

*Set the ignore count of breakpoint number bnum to count. The next count times the breakpoint is reached, your program’s execution does not stop; other than to decrement the ignore count, GDB takes no action.*

Answer (score 0):

I normally set a condition on a breakpoint.

```
(gdb) break <line> if i == 703
```